# How to insert entity fields with default values for the first time when Database created in android

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have to insert values to entity only first time when app installed is there a way to insert from where Database is created and later i can update fields using repository. I need to insert only first time.

Answer (score 0):

in the dataClass you can initial fields

```
data class Example(
val id: Int = 0,
val image: String = R.drawble.example,
val link_type: Int = 0,
val link_value: String = "example"
```

)